# C# SQLServer duda con ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Buenas, tengo una duda, estoy cargando un `ComboBox` con datos de `SQLServer` en `C#` de la siguiente manera;:

```
    public List<Organizadores> organizadores(string usuario)
    {
        List<Organizadores> salida = new List<Organizadores>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT V_Nombre_Organizadores.NombreOrg AS NombreOrg, Sucursal_Organizador.RO_CodigoProvidus AS RO_CodigoProvidus " +
                         "FROM Sucursal_Organizador " +
                         "INNER JOIN V_Nombre_Organizadores ON Sucursal_Organizador.RO_CodigoProvidus = V_Nombre_Organizadores.CodOrg " +
                         "WHERE Sucursal_Organizador.SUCU_id = (SELECT IdSucu FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario = @usuario)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Organizadores organizadores1 = new Organizadores("000", "Todo");
                    salida.Add(organizadores1);
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Organizadores organizadores = new Organizadores();
                        organizadores.codigo= dr["RO_CodigoProvidus"]?.ToString();
                        organizadores.nombre = dr["NombreOrg"]?.ToString();
                        salida.Add(organizadores);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y luego hago esto:

```
    private void cargarOrganizadores(string usuario)
    {
        conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        cmbOrganizadores.ValueMember = "RO_CodigoProvidus";
        cmbOrganizadores.DisplayMember = "NombreOrg";
        cmbOrganizadores.DataSource = conexionSQL.organizadores(usuario);
    }
```

Pero, al momento de mostrar el valor del código en un messageBox (supongamos AAA-123) me muestra el nombre de la persona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo necesito que me muestre el nombre: **"(Fulanito)"** y que pase el código: **"(AAA-123)"**. Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
    private void btnAutos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string codigo = lblCodigoUsuario.Text;
        int valor = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipoPlan.SelectedValue.ToString());
        if(cmbOrganizadores.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cmbOrganizadores.SelectedValue.ToString());
            //string todo = "TODO";
            //ReporteCertificado reporteCertificado = new ReporteCertificado(codigo, todo, valor);
            //reporteCertificado.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cmbOrganizadores.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```

La clase:

```
class Organizadores
{
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; } 
    

    public Organizadores(string codigo, string nombre)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Organizadores() { }
    

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return nombre.ToString();
    }
}
```

Entiendo que,al sobre-escribir el método **ToString()** este me trae el nombre, pero de no setearlo no me trae el nombre sino: **AppEscritorio.Clase.Organizadores** ¿Lo estoy haciendo mal? E insisto, necesito que el `ComboBox` me muestre el nombre del organizador pero que en el `MessageBox` me muestre el código del organizador

Comment: de tu consulta, que campo es el que tiene ese código?

Comment: Este: `Sucursal_Organizador.RO_CodigoProvidus AS RO_CodigoProvidus` @L.Ronquillo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pon este código en el **evento OnClick** del botón:

```
var organizador = cmbOrganizador.SelectedValue.ToString();
var listaOrganizadores = (List<Organizadores>)cmbOrganizadores.DataSource;

var codigo = (from o in listaOrganizadores 
              where o.nombre == organizador
              select o.codigo).FirstOrDefault();

MessageBox.Show(codigo.ToString());
```

Primero guardamos en una variable el elemento seleccionado del **ComboBox** que sería el nombre, posteriormente hacemos un casteo a lista de organizadores de los elementos del **ComboBox**, este casteo convierte los elementos del **ComboBox** a una lista de organizadores, posteriormente usando **Linq** hacemos una consulta la cual nos va a devolver de esa lista de organizadores el elemento cuyo nombre es igual  a lo que está seleccionado en el **ComboBox** de esta consulta cogemos el código y es lo que mostramos.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado de maravilla.

Answer (score 1):

Me enfocaré como tal en el método `cargarOrganizadores`:

Tenemos 2 parámetros que tenemos que explicar:

- `ValueMember`: El valor que obtendrá el comboBox al ser seleccionado.
- `DisplayMember`: El elemento que se mostrará en el comboBox.

¿Cúal es la diferencia?

`ValueMember` generalmente se llena con el ID del registro, y `DisplayMember` con el texto que identifique el registro.

Con esto en cuenta, tu código debería de estar así:

```
private void cargarOrganizadores(string usuario)
{
    conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
    cmbOrganizadores.ValueMember = "RO_CodigoProvidus"; //si tienes un ID, podrías colocarlo aquí
    cmbOrganizadores.DisplayMember = "RO_CodigoProvidus"; //lo que se verá en el comboBox
    cmbOrganizadores.DataSource = conexionSQL.organizadores(usuario);
}
```

¡Saludos!

Comment: Sí, pero yo necesito que se vea el nombre y que el ValueMember tenga el ID.Es por eso que en el `ValueMember` tengo el `"RO_CodigoProvidus"` y en el `DisplayMember` el `"NombreOrg"`